# Show more time details in a correlation pairplot graph based on time series data

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pivot, seaborn

I have been measuring the air quality in my flat since a while, after being noticing an exposure to second-hand smoke coming from the downstair flat (...). I am using a PMS5003 sensor mounted on an enviro+ attached to a Raspberry. Until recently, I had only measured small particles, but I managed to add gas measurements recently. I am interested to see if there is a **correlation between the different values.** My hypothesis is that CO and nh3 concentration in the air will be high (so the value read by the sensor low, cf. [Enviro+ explanation](https://learn.pimoroni.com/tutorial/sandyj/getting-started-with-enviro-plus)), when there is smoke entering the flat, which will collerate with high PM 2.5 values coming from combustion.

The data comes in a csv files like this:
 `pm2_5_combustion;2021-01-09 20:14:00;166.24242424242425`

which is then parsed to this:

```
air_quality = pd.read_csv("processed/pms5003_gas.csv", sep=";")
air_quality.info()
air_quality["unit"].unique()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> RangeIndex: 92208 entries, 0 to 92207 Data columns (total 3 columns):
#   Column   Non-Null Count Dtype  
 ---  ------   --------------  -----
0   unit     92208 non-null  object
1   time     92208 non-null  object
2   reading  86445 non-null  float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 2.1+ MB

array(['adc', 'gt_0_3um', 'gt_0_5um', 'gt_10um', 'gt_1um', 'gt_2_5um',
        'gt_5um', 'nh3', 'oxidising', 'pm10_atmos', 'pm10_dust',
        'pm1_atmos', 'pm1_ultrafine', 'pm2_5_atmos', 'pm2_5_combustion',
        'reducing'], dtype=object)
```

Hereunder are some of the codes I have been trying to use to achieve the goal.

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

air_quality = pd.read_csv("processed/pms5003_gas.csv", sep=";")
air_quality.info()
air_quality["unit"].unique()

air_quality["time"] = pd.to_datetime(air_quality["time"]) #did not work

air_quality = air_quality.rename(columns={"time": "datetime"}) #renaming the column did not change much

# C. picking the values I would like to see the correlation between the following values
datetime = air_quality[air_quality["datetime"] == "datetime"]
pm2_5 = air_quality[air_quality["unit"] == "pm2_5_combustion"]
pm10 = air_quality[air_quality["unit"] == "pm10_dust"]
ox = air_quality[air_quality["unit"] == "oxidising"]
red = air_quality[air_quality["unit"] == "reducing"]
nh3 = air_quality[air_quality["unit"] == "nh3"]

# D. Trying with the below, did not work:
air_quality["weekday"] = air_quality["time"].dt.weekday
air_quality["date"] = air_quality["time"].dt.date
air_quality["hm"] = air_quality["time"].dt.hour
air_quality["hour"] = air_quality["time"].dt.hour

air_quality["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(air_quality["datetime"])
air_quality["date"] = air_quality["datetime"].dt.date
air_quality["hour"] = air_quality["datetime"].dt.hour
air_quality["min"] = air_quality["datetime"].dt.minute

# A. Making a pivot and then picking the columns I would like to see the correlation
df = air_quality.pivot(index="datetime", columns="unit", values="reading")            
df2 = df[["pm2_5_combustion", "pm10_dust", "reducing", "nh3", "oxidising"]]

# B. I also tried to concatenate the columns like that (did not work either):
frames = [datetime, pm2_5, pm10, ox, red, nh3]
result = pd.concat(frames)

# I can calculate the correlation without problem
df2.corr(method='pearson')

# I can also create some correlation graphs with sns.pairplot
sns.pairplot(
    df2,
    #hue="hour",
    #plot_kws=dict(marker="+", linewidth=1),
    #diag_kws=dict(fill=False)
    )
```

What I am struggling with, is to get the "hue" parameter to work. With C and D above, I get this table:
[image: Desired table to have in pivot with date, hour, min]

It is ok, but somewhat I cannot get the date, hour and min values, after I use the .pivot function (?), which is what I believe prevents me to getting to this:
[image: Desired outcome with a breakdown of the different point here by species, but in my case, by hour of the day or other type of time]
[seaborn pairplot explanation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html)
I spent the whole yesterday trying things out and reading the pandas documentation, but I am short in idea as to what I should try next, hence my question here as an alternative to tossing my laptop on my smoking neighbour's face.

Comment: [`pandas.DataFrame.corr`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html)

Comment: Thank you. I did this previously and got the correlation results. A mathematician friend suggested me to plots the different variables together to see if the correlation were signficant or not. I used the `pairplot` for this. However, I am assuming they are different gases going around the sensor, and as the exposure to cigarette fumes is greater at nights, I was thinking to find a way to show time attribute of the different measurements. So, with the `hue=hour`, I was hoping to differentiate the different points by hour but I cannot get the columns date, hour, min in the `df2` Dataframe (?).

Answer (score 0):

This will probably not be the most neat and straightforward answer, but it worked. I guess, there is a better way to reset the index in some sort of way or another without having to do the following steps I did. If so, I will still be interested in knowing about it. I exported it to a csv (`to_csv('')` and re-opened it again `read_csv('')`, and then modified the type of the date information with `to_datetime()`.

```
df2.to_csv('clean.csv')
no_5 = pd.read_csv("clean.csv")
no_5["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(no_5["datetime"])
no_5["date"] = no_5["datetime"].dt.date #probably not necessary
no_5["hour"] = no_5["datetime"].dt.hour
no_5["min"] = no_5["datetime"].dt.minute
```

Probably not necessary, but I kept it to export the per minute value in csv, after using `.groupby()`, then `.unstack()`

```
no_5
del no_5["date"]
del no_5["min"]
```

and then the magic of pairplot:

```
sns.pairplot(no_5, hue='hour', corner="True", plot_kws=dict(marker="+", linewidth=1))
```

[image: Scatter plots for the different variables]

Nb. it looks a bit messy, and it is not very telling at this stage, but it shows high concentration of small particles with lower resistance for 'reducing' and 'nh3', meaning higher concentration of those type of gases in the late time of the day, when people are usually home.

Of course, as pointed by [Trenton McKinney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7758804/trenton-mckinney), the `.corr` methods will give you the different correlation value.

```
no_5.corr(method='pearson') #or other available methods
```